# sbt multiproject without common root

Tags: scala, sbt

how can you set a dependency on a sbt project which is not contained in the root folder / project?

I'm currently developing a library and want to simultaneously consume it in other projects. Basically the library should be a completely decoupled project in another folder structure.

The problem is that I couldn't figure out a good workflow to develop library and consumer in parallel since sbt apparently only allows dependencies going down the filesystem tree.

Thanks,
Otto

Comment: You might be able to use [RootProject](http://harrah.github.io/xsbt/latest/api/sbt/RootProject.html) with a `file("../library")` location.

Comment: Thanks, i think that tip went in the right direction. I added: .dependsOn(file("/Users/...myLib"))
.aggregate(file("//Users/...myLib")) and now the project is listed in the consumer sbt when using "projects" however it's not in the classpath yet. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: How do you know whether it's in the classpath? How do you verify it?

Comment: because the code doesn't compile? before i packaged the other project and added the jar to the unmanaged lib folder of the consuming project? But to be honest, I'm shooting in the dark and don't really understand how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, nameley ProjectRef

```
.dependsOn(ProjectRef(file("/some/path"), "projectName"))
.aggregate(ProjectRef(file("/some/path"), "projectName"))
```